# How to use Apache webserver as middleware component for OWIN?

Tags: .net, apache, signalr, owin, nancy

Is it possible to use Apache with OWIN?  I'm trying to make an OWIN-based web app using signal r and would like to use apache.  I cannot seem to find any examples for how to do this.  From my research online it seems like the only option may be to run a http handler on my app and somehow forward requests to the app from apache.  This would not be ideal, I would rather integrate apache as a piece of middleware the way OWIN is meant to be used.  Another limiting factor is that I am using .NET 4.0 (it would be a very hard sell to get management buy-in on updating tools to get 4.5+).  Originally I was using nancy as a webserver, which was working well, but other more senior engineers where I work don't like this and would rather I use a well-known webserver, mainly due to security/IA implications.

Comment: Re security and upgrading .NET: [starting January 12, 2016 Microsoft will no longer provide security updates, technical support or hotfixes for .NET 4, 4.5, and 4.5.1 frameworks.](http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research online, it seems that the only way to do this is to forward traffic to your application from apache, using it as a proxy.  I have also read some stuff online about running an asp.net application in apache using mod_mono but I'm not sure how that factors into OWIN and getting requests to go to your app, unless they too are forwarded.